# mysql query with SELECT IN SELECT in more efficient way

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Please help me optimize query about getting reccomended (rec) for movies. I have many records and query run quite slow. The following query run for 2 mins

```
   SELECT rec.toMovieID, sum(rec.score) 
   FROM rec 
   WHERE movieID in 
      (SELECT movieid as movieID FROM userFavorites as ufv WHERE ufv.userid = 29)
   GROUP BY rec.toAMovieID
   ORDER BY rec.score DESC
   LIMIT 10
```

Do you think I can optimize it more?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an inner join instead of a subselect

```
SELECT
    rec.toMovieID,
    sum(rec.score) 
FROM rec INNER JOIN userFavorites ON rec.movieID = userFavorites.movieid
WHERE
    userid = 29
GROUP BY rec.toAMovieID
ORDER BY rec.score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

You should set indexes on rows in where clause, at least for movieid and userid. (If not allready done)

Comment: Super. Working for me :) I would give you up, if I have enough points.

Comment: If there are duplicate records in `userFavorites` then this will return incorrect results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`:

```
   SELECT rec.toMovieID, sum(rec.score) 
   FROM rec r
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM userFavorites as ufv WHERE ufv.userid = 29 and ufv.MovieId = r.MovieId)
   GROUP BY rec.toAMovieID
   ORDER BY rec.score DESC
   LIMIT 10;
```

You have to be careful using a `join` because of duplicate records.

Comment: I agree. But looking at a functional level that can be prevented by introducing a unique index on `movieid` and `userid` in `userFavorites`.